# How to print out an "X" in java that takes the height from the user and the character from the user

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I need to create a method that takes an integer "height" and char argument "c" and prints out an "X" that is "height" characters tall using the special character in "c". My professor says it can be done using two loops but I think it needs more than that.

```
 public static void printX(int height, char c)
 {
     int i,j;
     int count=0; 

     for(i=0; i<height; i++)
     {
          count++; 
          for(j=0; j<count; j++)
          {
              System.out.print(" "); 
          }
          System.out.print(c);   
          System.out.println(); 
     }
 }
```

I started writing a code that only prints out one diagonal line and was trying to see if I could figure out how to do it from there but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to do this with two for loops?

Comment: Hint: There are two lines: `y = x` and `y = height - x`.  Print `c` if your `i` and `j` values solve either equation, else print a space.

Comment: If you don't use `i` or `j` outside your loop, declare them inside your `for`-statement: `for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

For height = 7, you want:

```
x     x
 x   x
  x x
   x
  x x
 x   x
x     x
```

1. The 1st line is 0 blanks, 1 char, 5 blanks, 1 char
2. The 2nd line is 1 blanks, 1 char, 3 blanks, 1 char
3. The 3rd line is 2 blanks, 1 char, 1 blanks, 1 char

See a pattern?

The middle line is special.

The remainder follow the same pattern as the top, but in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here we consider the height and j=i and j=height-i

```
public class printCross{

public static void main (String[] arg){

    Scanner keyboard =new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(" Please type a number grater than 2 :");
    int num=keyboard.nextInt();
    drawCross(num);

}

private static void drawCross(int num) {

int startCur = 0; 
int endCur = num-1; 
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{ 
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) 
{ 
if (startCur == endCur && j == i) 
System.out.print('*'); 
else if (startCur == j || endCur == j) 
System.out.print('*'); 
else 
System.out.print(' '); 
} 
startCur++; 
endCur--; 
System.out.println(); 
} 
}
```